# Frequent database backup workflow

Tags: mysql, workflow, backup, database-backups

We've got a database (mysql) driven application which contains business critical information, were looking at building a system that will allow us to backup the db frequently (say every 15 mins) essentially so that we minigate the danger of any data loss. Where torn between two setups :

Adding a backup jobs too a queue every 15 mins on a cron and storing these backups on another server. (To save space we would then delete most of these backups after 3 days, but keep the 06:00, 12:00, 18;00 hour versions.)

or

Is there a RAID like setup were all our data will be automatically copied to another hard drive or in this case server, in which case what would happen if we lost data, would the loss be carried to the other server (we would also run standard daily backups for our archives in edition to this) ?

or

Is there another established method for creating frequent backups ?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the optimal backup scheme would be following.

1. [Delayed slave](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-slave-delay.html). It allows you quickly restore your database in case of master failure. It *may* help in case of DROP DATABASE or other wrong SQL. So, you need something additionally.
2. Incremental backups every day with [Xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup) from the delayed slave. Optionally you could also check [TwinDB](https://twindb.com/backup/) for incremental backups.
3. As long as you need 15 minutes granularity you may pull binary logs from the master with [mysqlbinlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) from MySQL 5.6 (even if the master is 5.5 or 5.1). So, mysqlbinlog runs on a remote host and pulls logs from the master.

If you need to restore the database you have two ways.

1. If you can restore from the delayed slave you use that slave as a new master.
2. If on some reason you can't use the delayed slave (you missed the DROP command) then you restore last night copy from the incremental backup and apply binary logs since the last backup up to the moment of accident (again, if the accident is wrong DROP table you replay logs up to the last event before the DROP).

This schema will be optimal from performance standpoint (no impact on an application) and allows no data loss at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing backups more often than one hour, what you need is [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html). Setting up a secondary database server that can serve as a hot-standby is a lot better than abusing your database with repeated reads.

If you're backing up your database frequently, look at [innobackupex](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html) to snapshot your tables, or possibly [LVM snapshots](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html).

Comment: I'd like to second to the replication solution, but additionally I'd make delayed slave. In case of human mistake (accidental DROP TABLE, etc) you will have some time to prevent the bad query to be executed on the slave. Check pt-slave-delay tool ,  it does that http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-slave-delay.html

Comment: You can do of course incremental backups with Xtrabackup as tadman suggests. But again, it will have to read whole database in order to find pages that have changed since the last backup. So for really big databases when plain read will take longer than 15 minutes you can't take backups that often.

Comment: mylvmbackup is a nice tool for LVM snapshots, but in your case may not work for the same reason as incremental backups with XtraBackup.